# SQL -- merge only some columns from different tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which i would like to turn into one in a SELECT query by merging some columns together while having other columns remaining distinct.

first table (posts_article)

```
 id_post   id_user   title   content   published   nbr_comments   timestamp
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1         15        title1  text1     1           23             1111111111
 2         20        title2  text2     0           54             1122334455
```

second table (posts_text)

```
 id_post   id_user   message   nbr_comments   timestamp
 -------------------------------------------------------
 1         17        message1  15             1234567891
 2         22        message2  0              1987654321
```

expected result

```
 id_post   id_user   title   content   message    published   nbr_comments   timestamp
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1         15        title1  text1                1           23             1111111111
 2         20        title2  text2                0           54             1122334455
 1         17                          message1               15             1234567891
 2         22                          message2               0              1987654321
```

I've tried a few things but i can't really solve this. how can I get the expected result? What is the most efficient way to select that result?

EDIT: The logic of this merge is to be able to get all the different types of "posts" (submitted by users) at the same time.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you state more precisely what you want your join/merge logic to be? The example is pretty nice, but we're missing the purpose statement.

Comment: I just edited the post. (Not sure if I should've of answered or commented or whatever, I'm quite new to stackoverflow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT id_post, id_user,  title,  content, NULL AS message , published, nbr_comments, timestamp FROM posts_article
UNION
SELECT id_post, id_user, NULL as title, NULL as content,  message, NULL as published, nbr_comments, timestamp FROM posts_text
```

Comment: Thanks it works great but do you think it's the best way - ressource wise - to to this?

Comment: Usually if you are in the position to change your model it is best to do so. Imho every UNION is based on a design-flaw. If you are not able to change the model because the project is a brownfield project or something like this you need to live with it and the limitations.

Comment: Well the thing is basically users can post articles or short messages or pictures for example and I store each type of "post" in its table. So, to me, there are only three solutions to the problem of retrieving all the posts: 1)have as many requests as there are post types 2) UNION all the requests to get all posts at once 3) Store all types of posts in **one** database ressembling the "expected result" in this question and SELECT from there.

Comment: Ok you need to go with 1 or 2 .. 3 is no option however an alternative would be to use something like a document oriented approach to this(e.g. mongodb).

Comment: Yeah well that's the same conclusion I came to. Except that 2) seems better in the sense that i can sort the data with MySQL which is faster than with PHP.
As to mongodb, i'll check it out, thanks.